# Cube with the product uniform measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, terminology

Let $([0,1],\mathscr B([0,1]),\lambda)$ be the probability space where $\lambda$ is th Lebesgue measure and $\mathscr B([0,1])$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the unit interval $[0,1]$. Let us define a new probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathsf P)$ where
$$
  \Omega = [0,1]^\mathbb N
$$
and $\mathscr F$ is its product $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mathsf P$ is its product measure. I wonder if there is a standard name either for the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathscr F)$ - something like Hilber cube -  or even for the whole probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathsf P)$.

Comment: This space looks essentially like the coin flipping measure on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. There is an [isomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185240/strong-law-of-larger-numbers-with-coin-flips/185244#comment427468_185244) between the space of coin flips and Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and obviously, $\mathbb{N}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thanks! Sure, but I was just wondering about the terminology - whether there is a "canonical" name for $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathsf P)$

Comment: The unit hypercube?

Comment: I've certainly seen this construction several times without any special name given to it. So while I can't say that there is no special term for it, I'm pretty sure you don't break any convention by not naming it a certain way.

Comment: @Michael: thanks - I hope I got all the negations in your sentence correctly.

Comment: @Ilya If I was unclar: You are in good company if you don't use a specific term for this probabiliy space.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: finally, I've found the book I had in mind. In [Markov Models and Optimization, Section 23](http://www.amazon.com/Optimization-Chapman-Monographs-Statistics-Probability/dp/041231410X) Mark Davis calls $\Omega$ a *Hilbert cube* - rather than $(\Omega,\mathscr F)$ or $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathsf P)$. Hence, so far I can't remember either of seeing somewhere a special name for this measurable/probaility spaces. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've certainly seen this construction several times without any special name given to it. So while I can't say that there is no special term for it, I'm pretty sure you don't break any convention by not naming it a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the case where $\Omega =\{0,1\}$ (the coin flipping case) Tao calls this construction a "Bernoulli Cube" in his ["Introduction to measure theory", p. 241.](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf)

Comment: The very next example concerns the construction in the OP, and is called "the continuous cube" by Tao, however I'm not sure whether if I say that even among probabilists, I'll be understood.